# How to upload images in Siebel application for further sending via web service?

Tags: web-services, file-upload, applet, image-uploading, siebel

im newbie in Siebel CRM.
I have a task of creating form applet that has functionality of uploading images and also some text records. 
What I need to do is: send images and some text via WS(f.e. using SOAP) to external application and also save text information in siebel db.
My problem is that I cant create form applet with upload button and then submit button that processes given record as I described before.
PS: Appreciate if u give detailed information, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such functionality can easily be achieved using Siebel's attachment business components. For instance, under Service Requests, there is an attachments tab. Files can be uploaded here. Later for integration, your could simply use EAI Siebel Adapter BS in a Workflow, that will convert the binary attachment to base64 in the XML, which can be sent out. Users can upload any kind of file in different records.

Siebel OpenUI can show some images in Contact tiles uploaded into urls intead of files:
http://www.brucedaley.com/siebelobserver/2014/02/tiles-and-images.html

Comment: Hi, I actually tried attachment BCs but didnt succeed. Is this kind of BC can provide functionality of attaching imageS WHILE creating an entity ?
I know its lame, but, can you describe process of creating these kind of BCs and applets in shortly ?)

Comment: The attachment BCs are used for any binary file requirements. Check Integration Object: "ServiceReqIO", it has an Integration Component for "Service Request Attachment". If you have an SR (id:123) and it has an attachment uploaded in Siebel, if you use "EAI Siebel Adaptery" BS "Query" Method to query for SR Id:123, siebel will automatically convert the attachment to base64 in the SiebelMessage itself. We use this all the time to send binary attachments to integration.

Comment: Can it be done without using attachment BCs and tables ? 
In my applet I dont need to save image and information about it in siebel, we just need to send it through some WS.
Is your method can provide a button to browse file from client machine and on record save/submit button send the file? I mean, without attaching file to SR/Contact and etc...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without using attachment BCs, with ordinary JS code in PR/PM file. I had to do it so users can upload PDF files, which had to be base64 encoded and sent via WS afterward but not saved in Siebel. I've used JS `FileReader` object ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)) and JS out of the box base64 encoding ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)).